# Trying to install Xdebug on my remote server with PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug

I have a remote machine where runs an Apache Server. I want to use Xdebug on my local machine, using PhpStorm, to debug the PHP files located in my remote server.

Here is what I did on my remote Ubuntu server :

1. `apt-get install php7.2-xdebug`

2. Go to /etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini and add :

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/20180731/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.remote_host=<my local machine IP without braces>
xdebug.remote_log="/var/log/xdebug.log"
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
```

3. Restart Apache server `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

4. When I create a script with `echo phpinfo();` in it, it shows that Xdebug has been installed "correctly" (I guess) : it shows an Xdebug section with all the variables.

5. In PhpStorm, I set a breakpoint on a file, and I start listening to incoming debug sessions, I verify this by doing a netstat query that returns that my Mac has its process PhpStorm listening to port 9000

6. In Chrome browser, I download the extension Xdebug, and I open my script, where I added the breakpoint. The mapping between this file that I open in Chrome and the local files is correct.

7. I tap the button "debug" in the Chrome extension, it becomes green. I verified, the cookie is correctly sent as http headers has `XDEBUG_SESSION=PHPSTORM`

**Despite all of this, I cant achieve to have any incoming session on PhpStorm.**

I tried to see file `/var/log/xdebug.log` that I registered to be the log file of Xdebug, but this file is empty....

Did I forget something ? I have no idea what to do its been 8 hours I'm on it I have seen all post related to it on StackOverflow but nothing worked for me (I can't even manage to have something in `/var/log/xdebug.log` so I could see deeper what's going on). I have no idea if Xdebug is doing something when it receive my HTTP request.

Comment: 1) By "remote server" .. do you mean another computer on internet/LAN? Make sure that your Firewall/router allows incoming connection on Xdebug port. 2) Xdebug log will contain records when Xdebug will be trying to make any connections. If it does not .. then it means one of these: 1) file access permissions; 2) Xdebug does not see "debug me" flag (cookie or GET/POST param); 3) SELinux or alike that restricts Apache/Xdebug from doing what it needs to do (maybe more .. but those are the main ones AFAIK).

Comment: Try placing `xdebug_break();` in your code (programmatic breakpoint) -- will it make any entries in xdebug log now? You may also try telling Xdebug to debug every single request without waiting for "debug me" flag --`xdebug.remote_autostart=1`. Please also double check phpinfo output -- make sure that the values there (Xdebug section) is what you have configured. The main thing for now is to get entries in xdebug log. Then you can move further.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! www-data (apache user, on which php with xdebug runs), had no right to write in folder /var/log/. So I added the group of /var/log/ and now I have a log :) But still can't connect to phpStorm : "[6879] I: Connecting to configured address/port: <myLocalIP>:9000.
[6879] E: Time-out connecting to client (Waited: 200 ms). :-("
I disabled firewall on both machines (my local mac and my "remove server" which is a VPS with ubuntu on it), and I added the line in php.ini and checked that all the lines are in phpinfos)

Comment: 1) Double check the IP; 2) It still could be a firewall/router somewhere; 3) Ensure that it's PhpStorm that listens on local TCP 9000 (e.g. `sudo lsof -nP -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN`). On Mac, of you have local PHP installed, very often you may get php-fpm installed as well ... and it also uses 9000 port by default... 4) Bacasue of your other question, try SSH tunnel instead -- it doe not suffer from firewalls/IP changes.

Comment: To check firewall /router -- login to remote server and try to connect back to computer with IDE via `telnet` or `nc` using 9000 port -- if it makes connection then network is OK and it must be something else (SELinux perhaps etc).

Comment: “Telnet <mylocalip> 9000” command on my VPS  says “unable to connect to remote host : connection timed out”. I don’t understand...

Comment: lsof .... command says that phpstorm listen to port 9000 though

Comment: I got my local IP by doing curl ifconfig.me

Comment: As I try this tutorial https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/remote-debugging-via-ssh-tunnel.html to do ssh tunnel instead of direct connection, I have also a problem with step 2 as I said in the answer of lyq above : CLI interpreter window of phpstorm says that my server has no PHP installed because "failed to parse validation script output". Don't know if it would have any impact though

Comment: *"CLI interpreter window of phpstorm says that my server has no PHP installed because "failed to parse validation script output". Don't know if it would have any impact though"* You may not have enabled xdebug for CLI mode as you have edited one for Apache only (`/etc/php/7.2/apache2/php.ini`). If you do not plan to debug scripts in CLI mode then ignore that. P.S. When using ports by SSH, please make sure that the port you will be using is not busy on your server (e.g. 9000). Just in case you have pfp-fpm installed there as well. Using 9001 is more safer in this regard.

Comment: Used 9001 and typed command "ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 root@myhost" on local machine AND on server, changed nothing :/ I'm still trying to connect through real connection as I don't understand anything about this "SSH tunnel". Is it normal that : telnet mylocalIP 80 doesnt return anything too ? Looks like my local IP is not exposed to Internet. On my local Mac machine, it is said that port 9000 is being listened, though from my VPS, when I telllnet mylocalmachineIP 9000, connection time out ?_?

Comment: *"Used 9001 and typed command "ssh -R 9000:localhost:9000 root@myhost""* Better use 9001 everywhere where you see 9000.

Comment: *"Is it normal that : telnet mylocalIP 80 doesnt return anything too "* Did you run that command on a  server? Anyway: telnet either returns error or it is ready for accepting commands. You can try running that telnet command from your Mac and connect to your webserver. E.g. when I run `telnet 127.0.0.1 80` on my Windows machine ( I have local IIS installed), it will show me a blank screen. If I now type `GET /` and press Enter, I will get a HTML response of my index.php page.

Comment: TBH, I suggest to contact your hosting company (that offers that VPS) and check with them, they should know more about how their system works and what you may be missing.

Comment: Actually I think there is a problem with my local IP. My local machine is not exposed to Internet to act as a server (xdebug has to send the Debug infos to my IDE on my local machine so my VPS is the client and my local machine at home acts like a server). I called my internet provider and they told me that the IP I was using was the one of my home router and maybe my home router doesn’t know on which machine to transfer the request on my local network... but I have no idea on how to configure a router I’m bad at “networking” I should have listen more at my networking courses lol...

Comment: There is something I don’t understand though : how is it possible that I can contact my VPS from my local machine (sending http request) and get a response ? Im thinking : I get a response so my server DO has access to my local machine without any further configuration of my router. And, on which port of my local machine do I get the response, when I access a web page?

Comment: No, client is where IDE is running (debug client). But yes, Xdebug is the one that makes outgoing connections .. so SSH Tunnel will be good here as well (the previously mentioned firewall/router issue). As for the router -- you need to open the Xdebug port there and point to your local machine: it will then pass ALL incoming connections to that port to your local Mac. Different routers may have different names for this, but most commonly used it Port Forwarding. Check https://portforward.com/

Comment: *"how is it possible that I can contact my VPS from my local machine (sending http request) and get a response ?"* It works because it's an outgoing connection -- data returned back by the web server passes through already established connection. While Xdebug makes NEW connection to your computer (which basically "a server" here in this regard) and your router (firewall in a router) does not allow random incoming connections to pass through.

Comment: *"And, on which port of my local machine do I get the response, when I access a web page?"* Random port each time. it's an outgoing connection so that does not really matter here.

Comment: Thank you for you answers:) maybe when I access a webpage from my Mac, it opens a TCP connection that holds all the informations to find my machine precisely so VPS know exactly where to send it, while when it comes to create a TCP connection from VPS, I only have this little IP and no more information so TCP connection doesn’t go to my Mac ? Maybe I should read about how TCP works to understand why an outgoing connection doesn’t need IP on “http level” to know where to send back the response ?

Comment: I would like to bypass port forwarding and all this setup of my router but I still can’t manage to create ssh tunnel following the instructions on the tutorial.. maybe I could see ssh logs somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

you phpstorm'configure is maybe error.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have a problem here : instead of having "PHP Version : 7.2, config file : ...", I have : PHP Version : not installed. When I try to refresh (refresh button on the right), it says "failed to parse validation script output". Though, the path on my remote machine is correct. When I do "/usr/bin/php7.2 -i" on my machine, it returns the php info, and "/usr/bin/php7.2 -v" says "PHP 7.2 [.....] with Xdebug v2.7.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2019, by Derick Rethans"